# Code position in java two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, encoding

I want to code positions in a two-dimensional array in Java with dimension of [n][n]

we have n rows  and n columns, so what i want to achieve from this perspective is

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2)  
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2) 
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2)
```

I have to get this result ( code row and col to get the result in decimal):

```
(0) (1) (2) 
(3) (4) (5)
(6) (7) (8)
```

Comment: Ok. What is the problem? Did you read the [section on Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) in the Java Tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

For two-dimensional indices in `matrix[i][j]`, and a linear index in `vector[index]` the following relation holds.

```
final int n = 3; // dimension of the columns

int i = ...
int j = ...

int index = i * n + j;

i = index / n;
j = index % n;
```

Integer division and modulo is used.

Comment: @Unihedron Thanks, indeed I got a telephone call, In general this question concerns very elementary computer science / math, so much cannot be gained. I merely answered as the first answer was not complete.

Answer (score 0):

(n * row + column) would give you those indices. Is that what you're asking?

Here is the code for it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = i*n + j;
```